# Show svg if mime-type equals text/xml

Tags: svg, mime-types

I am trying to use an svg-image on my home-page,
basicly using following code:

```
<html><head/><body>
<img src="images/avatar.svg" width="135mm" height="210mm"/>
</body></html>
```

Everything goes fine on my pc (Linux with apache-server),
however after transfer to a very limiting host, the image is no longer shown.
(Note: Tested with Chrome29 and Opera12)

Reason for this: it is transferred under 'text/xml' instead of 'image/svg+xml'

What I am looking for is a way to show this image on my homepage, preferably without loosing the img-tag.

The tricky part about this:

- I have no access to the magic file
- I am not allowed to upload an .htaccess
- I have no server side scripting
- I do not want to use (i)frames
- Basicly I can only add (x)html, css, javascript

To ease some constraints:

- It does not need to work under IE

**EDIT:**
 Did already contacted support, they claim their host works as it should. So that is why I am looking for solutions (currently using .png, but ain't happy with that)

Comment: I'd say: contact the support. This is a clear missconfiguration, at least if that _really_ is a svg file you uploaded...

Comment: I'd recommend not using physical units. What happens if somebody looks at your site on a phone? The image will be bigger than the screen. I'd recommend the `rem` unit.

Comment: `image/svg+xml` is the officially registered mediatype for svg (see IANA), and it's not exactly new (apache has been shipping with the svg mimetype enabled per default for many years now). +1 for contacting the hosting company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a data URI (where you specify the content-type yourself), or you can use HTML5 which allows for inline SVG's (which would require you to drop the img tag).

http://jsfiddle.net/zy96L/4/:

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>Red circle</title>
<body>
    <img alt="red circle" src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle%20fill='red'%20cx='50'%20r='50'%20cy='50'%20/></svg>" />
```

(even validates)

Comment: Great idea,
combined with something like onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/avatar.png'" it might be even possible to just use the image file itself (without need to hard-code the image in the html).
Just need to see if the 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> part works in this, however the javascript could remove it if needed.
Tnx

Comment: if you want to use JavaScript, you can get an arraybuffer from the XHR object (if you set `responseType` accordingly) and use Blobs and [`window.URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.URL.createObjectURL) on them

Comment: Currently using this:
`<script type="text/javascript">
        function getSVG(source)
        {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", source, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return "data:image/svg+xml," + xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
</script>`

`<img src="images/avatar.svg"
        onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src = getSVG('images/avatar.svg')"/>`

And its working as wanted.

Tnx Again

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of Janus Troelsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557432/2466431) managed to help me with this.

Instead of directly embedding the image into the HTML, I'm using some javascript to retrieve the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getSVG(source)
     {
             xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.open("GET", source, false);
             xmlhttp.send();
             return "data:image/svg+xml," + xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
</script>
<img src="images/avatar.svg"
     onerror="this.onerror = null;
              this.src = getSVG('images/avatar.svg')"/>
```

This worked the server!